# How to use jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

This might be a stupid question, but how can I import the jQuery plugin below for my project?

https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/jquery.colorfy

I have already cloned the plugin from the link above, and unzipped it. The problem is that I don't know which file to add to my project folder or how to connect it properly. Please help!!

Comment: You want `jquery.colorfy.min.js` most likely.

Comment: should I pull it directly into my project? How can I access it @ceejayoz

Comment: Yoy should use the [releases](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/jquery.colorfy/releases) tab in Github

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the jquery.colorfy.min.js as suggested by @ceejayoz. You just need to add it into your project within a script tag, and ensure it's loaded AFTER jQuery.

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.colorfy.min.js"></script>
```

Then use jQuery to connect it to the desired element, as noted in the documentation on GitHub.

```
$("#your_text_area").colorfy("yourDescriptor");
```

You then use regular expressions to perform regular expressions against characters, and CSS classes to style them.

So to utilise the # character and the colour green, you would do as so:

```
$.fn.colorfy.textarea = {
   "title": /^\s{0,3}\#{1,6}.*$/m,
 };
```

With the CSS:

```
.textarea .title {
     color: #008000;
 }
```

Comment: I'm still fuzzy about the $.fn.colorfy.yourDescriptor = {
  "keyword": /function|typeof|instanceof|var/,
  "operator": /[+-*/%]/,
  "string": /(["']).*+\1/m
}. Could you explain for me how to use it?

Comment: Also, now my textarea has two ugly scrollbars coming out of nowhere.

Comment: The descriptors seem as though you can customise what can be used inside the text area. You use the left side as the keyword, and the right side as a regular expression identifier.

"currency": /\$/m,

He has quite a few examples on his markdown.js file.

Comment: so you mean if I want any word that start with # to turn green for example, I would do like this:  "keyword": /#/,?

Comment: To find a # in regex you would do: /^\s{0,3}\#{1,6}.*$/m YOu then add the colour using a CSS class based on your keyword. Let me update my answer. He has a demo page on GitHub here: https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/jquery.colorfy/blob/master/index3.html